# do i need to load jpg file for flex air mobile projects like as3?

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In a typical as3 or flex project, after loading xml file, i load jpg files (thumbnails etc) manually, so i can use them in sprites / movie clips etc..
currently i am working on air mobile project. and i am attempting to load some thumnails(jpg) file to list view (spark) and using custom item renderer.
itemrenderer has an spark image component in it. and its data property is set to Image object.
i can check that image files do exists in file application directory.
do i need to load all those thumbnails in memory. then use them?
image object will autoload source file object?? once assigned?
do i have to tell it explicitly to load file object? what events should i use to amke sure , image file object is loaded.?

any ideas?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally I'll edit and clean up posts but, this entire post is bad and there's a lot of fixing to do. Did you write this from a mobile phone? You should edit this and make it look presentable if you want to get any help.

Comment: thanks, i'll to write more formatted text from now on. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark images are really easy to work with. All you need is a url.

```
 <s:Image source="http://someimagesite.com/someimage.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

You can also use bitmap data or even embed directly into the source tag.

```
 [Embed(source="image.png")] private var myImage:Class
 mySparkImage.source = new myImage() as BitmapData;

 <s:Image source="@Embed('image.png')" />
```

Take a look:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-8000.html